# TSQL: Set in a variable the result of an Exec

Tags: t-sql, set, exec

My problem might be a little strange.

I have a variable column name (can have different but same position)

Later I want to use this column to take the information.

So I put in a variable the column name

```
Set @name = (Select COLUMN_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Test' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 1)
```

Then I want to get the information from this column:

```
EXEC('SELECT ' + @name + ' FROM Test Where id = 1')
```

This works but i need to put the result in another variable to be able to use it.
Or I can't find the way to do it.

I don't want to create a table to put the result, I want to find another way.

How can I set the exec in a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global temp table for this

```
DECLARE @name SYSNAME

SELECT @name = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Test' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 1

EXEC('SELECT ' + @name + ' INTO ##tmp FROM sys.objects')

SELECT * FROM ##tmp
```

Comment: the temp table will be delete by itself? because I do it in a while loop so it might not good

Comment: @usertfwr can you please edit your question to explain exactly what you are tryning to achieve and what you are currently attempting. Thanks.